# Проблемы с функцией array_search

Tags: php

Есть код php, который не пропускает формат jpeg, в чем проблема я уже понял, когда он находит формат jpeg в массиве, возвращает true и следом порядковый номер элемента, а номер элемента 0 и условие интерпретирует его как false. Как решить эту проблему?

```
if(isset($_POST['article-add'])) {

$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['article-image']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if (array_search($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) {
    echo "Такой формат есть";
    echo array_search($imageinfo['mime'],$arr);
}
else {
    echo "Такого формата нет";
    echo array_search($imageinfo['mime'],$arr);
}
}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="index.php" method="post">
        <label for="article-image">Картинка статьи:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="article-image" name="article-image">
        <button name="article-add" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Прочитать документацию? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php

Comment: @andreymal да ну, бред какой-то)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Эта функция может возвращать как логическое значение FALSE, так и
>   значение не типа boolean, которое приводится к FALSE. За более
>   подробной информацией обратитесь к разделу Булев тип. Используйте
>   оператор === для проверки значения, возвращаемого этой функцией.
>   
>   https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php

Из чего следует, что вам необходимо использовать оператор `===`, а вашем случае его эквивалент НЕ равно: `!==`.

Ваш код:

```
...
if (array_search($imageinfo['mime'],$arr) !== false) {
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Просто пушечный ответ!